# Haskell - code explanation

Tags: haskell

```
function x i xs = let l = i `mod` length xs in take l xs ++ x : drop (l + 1) xs
```

can anyone explain to me what does let do here, what it stands for and what does in do here, what it stands for, and what is l

Answer (score 2):

This defines a function (unimaginatively) called `function`. It takes 3 arguments, `x`, `i` and `xs`. It's worth noting the type signature

```
 function :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
```

The body of the function is to the right of the `=`. Let's reindent it for clarity

```
let l = i `mod` length xs 
in take l xs ++ x : drop (l + 1) xs
```

So `l` is `i` modded with the length of `xs`, and we take `l` elements from `xs` and append that to `x : drop (l+1) xs`. This will drop `l + 1` elements from `xs` and put `x` in front.

Now rather than telling you what it's for, here are some sample inputs and their results

```
function 2 2 [1, 2, 3]
> [1, 2, 2]
function 0 (-1) [3, 3, 3]
> [-1, 3, 3]
```

Since this looks like homework, I'll let you figure out the pattern.

This is pretty basic Haskell, and if this is for a class, I strongly urge you to read [Learn You A Haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com), it's great for learning the basics.

Comment: ty, just tell me what does this part of the code do: x : drop (l + 1) xs

Comment: @user3088738 he part of the answer that says "This will drop `l+1` elemtns from xs and put `x` in the front", That's what it does :)

Comment: and do you know here:
insert2D :: a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]] /n
insertD x i j xss = function r' j xss where /n
  r  = xss !! (j `mod` length xss) /n
  r' = function x i r /n
what does xss !! 
i wrote /n for new row

Comment: @user3088738 Please don't post whole new questions in the comments, that would belong in a separate question. But again, **we're not here to do your homework**. As was explained in your other question, StackOverflow isn't a place to just post your homework questions. Ask a TA or a prof.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps read the code better when it is presented with some whitespace added:

```
function x i xs = let l = i `mod` length xs
                  in take l xs ++ x : drop (l + 1) xs
```

`let` binds the variable `l` to the expression `` i `mod` length xs ``.  The value of the overall expression is then

```
take l xs ++ x : drop (l + 1) xs
```

where here you use the value for `l` as given above.  There's another way of expressing this in Haskell:

```
function x i xs = take l xs ++ x : drop (l + 1) xs
     where l = i `mod` length xs
```

This way round it can often read more naturally.

Comment: ty, just tell me what does this part of the code do:
x : drop (l + 1) xs